# Cannot resolve JSON dependency using Maven -- Object not found

Tags: java, json, maven, intellij-idea

I'm fairly new to Java (and especially to Maven) and am trying to compile a JavaFX application using the Google Firebase Admin SDK.

I'm building using Maven in IntelliJ IDEA, and while my application can pull other files from the `resources` directory (PNG images, specifically) without a hitch, as soon as I try to compile my app using the Firebase initialization snippet as provided by Google, I am presented with the error: `Exception in Application start method... Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: [database JSON name].json (The system cannot find the file specified)`

I have the following code in the main class, copied directly from the Firebase SDK documentation. The snippets in square brackets are, as you can probably tell, placeholder names. The line to which the IntelliJ console points is the first one below, starting "`FileInputStream`."

```
FileInputStream serviceAccount =
                new FileInputStream("[database JSON name].json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://[database name].firebaseio.com")
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

In my `pom.xml` file, I have the dependencies below:

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>main</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
        <artifactId>firebase-admin</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

   </dependencies>
```

Given that every other resource that Maven is pulling from is in the `resources` folder and is being called just fine, I'm confused as to why Maven is unable to locate the JSON file being called in a similar way from the same folder. If anyone could help point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

**Notes:** I've tried building both with and without the JSON dependency in `pom.xml`. I'm not sure if I have the correct version or not, anyway. Additionally, I have tried moving the JSON file to the source code directory and redirecting the reference to the new location but to no avail.

Comment: do u have given the correct path of json file which you want to load?

Comment: just use classloader to load your file  like   InputStream input=                                                                  YourClassName.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName)                                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(new JSONTokener(input));

Comment: Your current working directory is most likely not what you expect it to be.

Comment: The assumption you are making about the location of your files is wrong. Furthermore why are you using such an ancient version of JUnit and what kind of scope is it defined into `<scope>main</scope>` this is simply wrong. I would suggest to use `<scope>test</scope>` instead.